# Copy all files except .map files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using the ncp plugin to copy files in nodejs, and in the option filter is described as following:

> options.filter  - a RegExp instance, against which each file name is
> tested to determine whether to copy it or not, or a function taking
> single parameter: copied file name, returning true or false,
> determining whether to copy file or not.

But when I add a filter on .map files (since I want to copy everything except .map files) nothing is copied, and here is my code:

```
ncp(path.join(distPath, asset), path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName, asset), {
        clobber: false,
        filter: /\.(map)$/,
      });
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning the filter into a function.

```
ncp(path.join(distPath, asset), path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName, asset), {
    clobber: false,
        filter: function (f) {
            f.endsWith(".map");
        },
    }
);
```

It was working here https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp/issues/125